# Integral $\int \frac {\sin x} {\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$\int \frac {\sin x} {\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}} dx$

**My attempt:** Obviously, we can call $u=\cos x \implies du=-\sin x dx$ and rest can be done.

However, I thought at the beginning the following: I can rewrite integrant as $$\int \frac {\sin x dx} {\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}=\int \frac {\sin x dx}{|\sin^2 x|}$$

But I couldn't continue because I don't know how to seperate absolute value because of indefinite integral. So, is there any mistake about my idea?

Comment: Why isn't $\sqrt{1 - \cos^2 x} = \sqrt{\sin^2 x} = |\sin x|$?

Comment: @User0 your integrand is not correct.

Comment: @User0 I mean the integrand is **not** $\csc x$.

Comment: @dfnu, i get it now, i took the generic case of cancelling out sinx, thanks for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|\sin^2 x|=\sin^2x, $$ since its always positive. Also notice that you have something like $$\int \frac{-f'(x) }{\sqrt{1-f(x) ^2}}dx, $$ that's arcosine..

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks

Comment: Notice that the denominator is in fact $|\sin x|$.

Answer (score 0):

Your integrand is just
$$\frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}=\begin{cases}1 & (2k\pi <x < (2k+1) \pi)\\ -1 & ((2k+1)\pi <x< (2k+2) \pi) \end{cases}, \ \ \ k\in \mathbb Z.$$
(See figure below, blue plot.) Therefore the primitive functions are all the functions of the form
$$F(x) = \begin{cases}x + C_{a_k} &  (2k\pi <x < (2k+1) \pi)\\
-x + C_{b_k} & ((2k+1)\pi <x< (2k+2) \pi)
\end{cases},\ \ \ k \in \mathbb Z,
$$
(with $C_{a_k}$ and $C_{b_k}$ arbitrary constants) obviously defined for $x \neq k\pi$.

One of the primitive is, e.g. $$\arccos(\cos x), \ \ \ x\neq k\pi$$ (see graph below, red plot) or
$$x \cdot \mbox{sign} (\sin x) + \frac{\pi}2,\ \ \ k \neq k\pi$$
(yellow plot).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\because \sqrt{1-\cos ^2 x}=\sqrt{\sin ^2 x}=|\sin x|$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\therefore \int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos ^2 x}} d x 
& =\int \frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|} d x \\
& =x \operatorname{sgn}(\sin x)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: It's probably better to emphasize that the constants can be taken arbitrarily and also different for each interval in which the funciton (and the primitive) is defined. For example one can have a primitive with jump discontinuities or removable discontinuities such as $\arccos(\cos x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\cos x$, then $d u=-\sin x d x$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos ^2 x}} d x & =-\int \frac{d u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \\
& =\arccos u+C \\
& =\arccos (\cos x)+C
\end{aligned}
$$